# How to hide country parameters on page load via jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery

How to hide country parameters on page load via jquery ajax php.

The code below display results from database and its working fine.

I can **hide/unhide or toggle** all the **country values** each separately via its id when button is click and is working good.

**Here is my issue:** How can I hide only the all country values on page load so that I can toggle or hide/unhide it as usual.

here is my coding effort so far
[image: screenshot showing arrows pointing to country values that i want to hide on page load]

```
<html>
    <head>
  <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script>
//toggle div on click

       $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".hideunhide_country").click(function(){
             var id = this.id; 
               $("#result_"+id).toggle( 'slow', function(){

               });
            });
         });

/*

//hide unhide div on click
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hideunhide_country").click(function(){
var id = this.id; 
$("#result_"+id).hide();

  });
});
*/

</script>



        <div class="content">

            <?php

include('db.php');
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users order by id');
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {


$id = $row['id'];
$country = $row['country'];



            ?>

                    <div class="p">
 <h1>Userid: <?php echo $id; ?></h1>


//hide country values on page load
<div id="result_<?php echo $id; ?>">
 <h1><?php echo $country; ?></h1>
</div>

<input type="button" value="HideUnhide" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="hideunhide_country"  />

</div>


            <?php

                }
            ?>



        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a PHP issue is it? Please click edit, then `[<>]`  snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with JS, HTML and CSS ONLY

Comment: Hide it initially with CSS

Comment: `[id^=result] { display:none }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a qucik fix, you schould refactor your code...

```
<html>
    <head>
  <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script>
//toggle div on click

       $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".hideunhide_country").click(function(){
             var id = this.id; 
               $("#result_"+id).toggle( 'slow', function(){

               });
            });
            // hide all countries
            $("[id^='result_']").hide()
         });

/*

//hide unhide div on click
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hideunhide_country").click(function(){
var id = this.id; 
$("#result_"+id).hide();

  });
});
*/

</script>



        <div class="content">

            <?php

include('db.php');
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users order by id');
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {


$id = $row['id'];
$country = $row['country'];



            ?>

                    <div class="p">
 <h1>Userid: <?php echo $id; ?></h1>


//hide country values on page load
<div id="result_<?php echo $id; ?>">
 <h1><?php echo $country; ?></h1>
</div>

<input type="button" value="HideUnhide" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="hideunhide_country"  />

</div>


            <?php

                }
            ?>



        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```